# How can i compare a time in a data table against current time using a timer control?

Tags: sql, vb.net, time

I am trying to create an application that will execute a SQL query stored in a dataset when the Start Time against that query matches the current real time. I am trying to do this using a timer control so every tick (1 second) it compares times and if the time matches, it will execute the SQL query.

Think along the lines of a custom SQL Server Agent Job application that is more easy for non SQL users to set up.

I have all my SQL jobs stored in a shared datatable called "homeDataTable".
I have my timer setup to tick every second, and the intention is to check current time vs the time stored in homeDatatable, and if a check is successful, it will call a background worker to start the task based on the ID stored against the SQL job with the matching time.

The piece i am missing/not understanding is how to compare the two times (timer vs data in data table).

This is what i currently have:

```
Public Shared Function CheckTask()

    'Compare task time to current real time every second
    Dim dp As New DataProxy
    Dim tc As SettingsDataSet.ScheduledTasksDataTable = homeDataTable
    Dim tr As DataRow

    For Each tr In tc
      'Compare tr time vs current time

      'If match, execute the below and send through the task ID
      RunTask()
    Next



    Return 0

  End Function
```

A timer control is calling this function every tick. This is the timer function:

```
  Private Sub tmrTask_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTaskCheck.Tick

    ucBusinessLogic.CheckTask()

  End Sub
```

Is someone able to please point me in the right direction on how i can compare real time vs the time on each row in my data table?

I am using VS Community 2017 and .NET Framework 4.8.03752.

Please let me know if any more information is required and i'll be happy to supply it.

EDIT - EXTRA INFO
The 'Current Time' i am storing as a text in a label which is updated with a timer as shown below:

```
  Private Sub tmrCurrentTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCurrentTime.Tick

    'Display current date/time, updates every second
    lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString

  End Sub
```

This is ultimately the time i am trying to compare against the 'Run Time' stored against each specific task in the homeDataTable.

Comment: I don't think you can store an SQL query in a `DataSet`. You could store a query string in a `DataTable` or the result of a query could be a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`. It would be hard to match current real time down to the second to anything. I don't see any timer control in your code. What exactly is in `homeDataTable`? Strings? DateTime values? Integers? What have you tried to compare the times? Add the code to your question and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @Mary Sorry, you are right. I have updated the title and question to show the timer control. In the homeDataTable are a variety of columns such as the task ID (uniqueidentifier), start date/time (datetime) end date/time (datetime), task SQL (nvarchar) and a few others.

Comment: Don´t reinvent the wheel. Use an existing schedule framework like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It is easy to use and yet very powerful. And most importantly pretty exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"every tick (1 second) it compares times"*. Why would you do that? When you set an alarm on a clock or a phone, do you check the time every second to see if it's time for the alarm or do you just wait for the alarm to go off at the right time? Why set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to 1 second when you can set it to the exact amount of time until you want to execute the query? E.g.

```vb
'Execute the query at 6.00 PM today.
Dim queryTime = Date.Today.AddHours(18)

Dim timeUntilQuery = queryTime - Date.Now

Timer1.Interval = CInt(timeUntilQuery.TotalMilliseconds)
Timer1.Start()
```

The `Timer` will then `Tick` pretty much exactly at the right time.

Here is an example of using one `Timer` for multiple tasks:

```vb
Private table As DataTable
Private taskRows As Queue(Of DataRow)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Populate table here.

    'Create queue of tasks in chronological order.
    taskRows = New Queue(Of DataRow)(table.Select().OrderBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Date)("QueryTime")))

    'Set the Timer for the first task.
    SetTimer()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim row = taskRows.Dequeue()

    'Set Timer for next task.
    SetTimer()

    Dim query = row.Field(Of String)("Query")

    'Execute query here.
End Sub

Private Sub SetTimer()
    Timer1.Stop()

    If Not taskRows.Any() Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim row = taskRows.Peek()
    Dim queryTime = row.Field(Of Date)("QueryTime")

    Timer1.Interval = CInt((queryTime - Date.Now).TotalMilliseconds)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The intention of comparing the times is because there will be multiple rows within the data table that each contain their own run time. I could add a timer as you say but then i would need a timer for every task saved in the data table. As the data table is dynamic, e.g. tasks can be removed and added on a whim, i dont think this would work. This is why i am trying to compare times.

Comment: @L.Moy you don't need a timer for *each* task, just for the *next* one

Comment: @L.Moy, as suggested, you only need one `Timer`. You simply order the rows by time and set the `Interval` appropriately for the next one. When the `Timer` `Ticks`, you reset the `Interval` again for the next. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that is incredibly clever, thank you for your knowledge. i've been able to get this working by also splitting it up and allocating certain parts to my business logic layer and calling the functions from my main form. Truly appreciated, thanks.